# deploy 2 apps , static react and angular on 1 nginx ( with docker)

Tags: reactjs, apache, docker, nginx, react-router

I would like to deploy 2 apps over Nginx  and docker

1- react app using serve -s - a static file that should run on the root

2- php + angularjs app with apache

The issue is when I open the page like http://url/old/test#

I got 2 pages merged to 1 - because also go a PHP page (with static angular js) and also got the 404 pages from the new app because I have a react-router that print 404 page

the new one need to to know the http://url/old  but only as an api calls but it should not affect on the

how can I fix it. ?

My Nginx is as follows:

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://react:5000/;
      limit_req zone=gateway_limit burst=100 nodelay;

      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    }

    location /old {
      proxy_pass http://docker-service:8080/;
      limit_req zone=gateway_limit burst=100 nodelay;

      # Force path '/' to only use https
      add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
      if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri/old;
      }
    }

|
```

Comment: I am not an expert in nginx but as per the configuration its seems like if we call localhost:8080/ then it will redirect to  http://react:5000/ and if we call localhost:8080/old then it will redirect to http://docker-service:8080/ which is again come in docker over 80 port so it will again go http://react:5000/ .Please clarify the fact

Comment: yes @NiteshSharma
and I got 2 pages  in the old app , half of the page is new and half is old

Comment: Is it not a loop you call the first URL that is calling second and in the second you are again calling first ?